# how to modify flutter_tree package for select all children?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

i using  [flutter_tree](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tree) for create tree of chackbox in flutter.

I want all children to be checked when I check a parent item, and all children to be unchecked if I uncheck a parent.

The source code on GitHub is:
https://github.com/esmaeil-ahmadipour/flutter_chckbox_tree

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [`list_treeview` package](https://pub.dev/packages/list_treeview), if you don't want to deal with it yourself.  It has a `selectAllChild()` method.